# How to call custom component in CakePHP 2.0 version

Tags: cakephp, controller, components, call, custom-component

Am using 2.0 version and trying to call a method defined in my custom component file. Its throwing Fatal Error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function doComplexOperation() on a non-object in

app/Controller/DepartmentsController.php

```
<?php
class DepartmentsController extends AppController {
 public $component = array('ArrayToObject');

 function display() {
   $this->ArrayToObject->doComplexOperation(1,2);
 }
}
?>
```

Here is my component file:

app/Controller/Component/ArrayToObjectComponent.php

```
<?php
class ArrayToObjectComponent extends Component {
  public function doComplexOperation($amount1, $amount2) {
    return $amount1 + $amount2;
  }
}
?>
```

I am a newbee please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your code: it should be `$components` instead of `$component` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

What @dhofstet said.

Also:

```
<?php
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');
class ArrayToObjectComponent extends Component {
    public function doComplexOperation($amount1, $amount2) {
        return $amount1 + $amount2;
    }
}
```